# How to check all boxes when using function form_checkbox() php

Tags: javascript, php, checkbox

Hi guys i have two checkboxes.

```
<li>
   <?=form_checkbox('heart_rate', 'yes', sel_checkbox($admission['heart_rate'], $observation[0]->heart_rate))?> 
   <?=form_label('Heart Rate')?> 
</li>
<li>
   <?=form_checkbox('blood_pressure', 'yes', sel_checkbox($admission['blood_pressure'], $observation[0]->blood_pressure))?> 
   <?=form_label('Blood Pressure')?> 
</li>
```

i want to create a third checkbox labelled all so that when it is ticked all my checkboxes are ticked. Any ideas?

Comment: You can use JavaScript.

Comment: Is that CodeIgniter? Please update your tags.

Comment: __"i want to create a third checkbox labelled all"__ what problem you are facing to create third checkbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Useing jQuery this can be done very easily, just give id to the check all checkbox `checkAllId`:

And the following code will check all the checkbox:

```
 $('#checkAllId').change(function(){

    if($(this).attr('checked')){
     //uncheck all the checkboxes   
     $("input[type='checkbox']").each( 
       function() { 
          $(this).attr('checked',false);
       } 
     );
   }else{
      //check all the checkboxes  
      $("input[type='checkbox']").each( 
       function() { 
          $(this).attr('checked',true);
       } 
     ); 
   }
});
```

you will have to give id to checkbox as:

I think you have not given id properly try this :

```
  <?php
     $data = array(
            'name'=> 'checkAllId',
            'id'=> 'checkAllId',
          );

  form_checkbox($data)

 ?>
```

Also confirm in the firebug whether id is coming properly or not.

Hope this will help!

Comment: hi sandip i am new to this. Would this code for the check all box be appropriate <?=form_checkbox('checkAllId')?> <?=form_label('All Observations')?>

Comment: @user257033 do you use jquery? if yes then above code will work

Comment: wow it worked perfectly sandip. but just before you go how do i modify your javascript so that rather than checking all the boxes based on the input type it checks specific boxes based on the id. so for example if i only want this box checked( <?=form_checkbox('heart_rate', 'yes', sel_checkbox($admission['heart_rate'], $observation[0]->heart_rate))?> ) rather than all the boxes

Comment: also it doesnt uncheck when the checkall is clicked again

Comment: hi sandip you missed my question about how do i target the id of the checkbox rather than the type checkbox so i can specify which boxes i want ticked....last question :,)

Comment: @user257033 if you want to specific checkbox to checked you can click on that directly, and if you want all the checkbox of particular group to be checked then give a class to every checkbox and then `"input[type='checkbox.classofCheckboxes']"` while selecting

Comment: @user257033 can you remake this one : you missed my question about how do i target the id of the checkbox rather than the type...

Comment: @user257033 not question remake the comment

Comment: yea you want me to remake my question to include the comment comment

Comment: @user257033 I didn't understood the last question, can you explain in detail

Comment: basically i said how do i create a class for the checkboxs when they are coded like this <?=form_checkbox('heart_rate', 'yes', sel_checkbox($admission['heart_rate'], $observation[0]->heart_rate))?> <?=form_label('Heart Rate')?>

Comment: @user257033 you will have to similar to this ` <?php
     $data = array('name'=> 'checkAllId','class'=>'classofCheckboxes'); form_checkbox($data)`
?> for every checkbox that you want to give a class

Comment: so were would i put the data class here...<?=form_checkbox('heart_rate', 'yes', sel_checkbox($admission['heart_rate'], $observation[0]->heart_rate))?> <?=form_label('Heart Rate')?>  so it does not affect the other attributes of the checkbox

Comment: @user257033 please follow the same way that I have given in the answer for setting id for select all checkbox, see my previous comment carefully

Comment: no sandip you dont understand your code works and the select all checkbox is fine. Its the idividual checkboxes that i have an issue with. I want to preserve all the properties of each individual checkbox but bge able to attach a class to the ones i wish to be controlled by the select all checkbox. so would i code one of these checkboxes like so.... <?=form_checkbox($data,'heart_rate', 'yes', sel_checkbox($admission['heart_rate'], $observation[0]->heart_rate))?> <?=form_label('Heart Rate')?> .... were $data is array('name'=> 'checkAllId','class'=>'classofCheckboxes');

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    $('input[class=3rd]').on('click',function(){
        var this = $(this);
        if($(this.':checkbox:checked').length > 0)
        {
            // If 3rd is checked, check all
            $('.1st').prop('checked', true);
            $('.2nd').prop('checked', true);
        }
        else
        {
            // Esle uncheck all
            $('.1st').prop('checked', false);
            $('.2nd').prop('checked', false);
        }
    })
})
```